# is using res.locals decrease the performance in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

i was told that using res.locals will decrease the performance of my application , and it's better to attach variables on the request.
in my case i want to attach variables that are accessible only on the server side , and i don't want it to be sent back to the user , and i also came across sending the variable using
**next(value)**  , what is the best approach for my case??

i have this middleware that gets the id of the user from jwt

```
jwt.verify(
        accessToken,
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
        function (err, payload) {
          if (err)
            return res.status(401).send({
              status: "failure",
              response: "access token is not valid",
            });
          id = payload.id;
        }
      );
      res.locals.userId = id;
      next();
```

then this middleware that gets the role of the user based on the id

```
const RoleId = await sequelize.models.User.findByPk(res.locals.userId);
    if (RoleId === 1) {
      res.locals.title = "Admin";
      next();
    } else {
      res.locals.title = "Customer";
      next();
    }
```

Comment: _"i was told that using res.locals will decrease the performance of my application"_... Who told you that? Did you ask them to clarify?

Comment: people telegram group ,no , i didn't ask for clarification ,

Comment: How exactly is _"attaching variables on the request"_ any different to [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)? Sounds like exactly the same thing to me from a performance perspective. The only difference is that `locals` are automatically exposed to templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.locals.xxx` will have no different performance from setting `res.xxx` or `req.xxx`.  No difference at all. So, without a specific reference to whomever said one would be slower than the other that somehow has more context, that's not correct.

And, `res.locals` are not sent to the client.  Template engines doing server-side rendering by convention will look in `res.locals` to find variables that the template may reference that were not explicitly passed to `res.render()`.  This is very useful for having common data (like a user's name) that you want the template to use, but don't want to have to manually pass to every single `res.render()` call.

This is entirely under your control since you, on the server, control both the template and the server-side rendering.  This allows you to insert things into the page which is then sent to the user, but nothing goes in the template that you don't put there.  So, `res.locals` is not a security risk unless you somehow give an outside agent control over your template (which would be subject to all sorts of security issues beyond just `res.locals`.

Another advantage of `res.locals` is that its an independent namespace that is entirely reserved for your use.  No variable you use there will conflict with any existing functionality of the `http` class or Express or whatever web server engine you're using.  The `res` object, on the other hand, has all sorts of existing methods and properties that you have to make sure you don't overwrite.  So, `res.locals` is safer in that regard as it is specifically reserved for your own use.  You can put any named property in there without any risk of conflict.

Passing a value to `next(value)` is how you abort further routing and immediately invoke your error handler, passing `value` to the error handler.  This is not how middleware communicates data to downstream routing or rendering.

Both your code examples look like proper use of `res.locals` to me.  That is exactly what it's for.

---

On a completely separate topic, your first code example has a coding error in it.  You need to put these:

```
res.locals.userId = id;
next();
```

Inside the `jwt.verify()` callback.  `jwt.verify()` is asynchronous.  You won't have the `id` value until that callback is called.  It should be like this:

```
jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, function(err, payload) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: "failure",
            response: "access token is not valid",
        });
    }
    res.locals.userId = payload.id;
    next();
});
```